# Are Bundles of vector spaces equivalent to sheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

From the basics of sheaf theory I know that we have an equivalence between sheaves on a topological space $B$ and certain spaces $\pi:E \to B$ over $B$. This is equivalence is given on one hand by the functor
\begin{equation}
    E \mapsto (U \mapsto \Gamma(U, E))
\end{equation}
its quasi-inverse is given by defining a topology on $\coprod_{b \in B}F_b$, where $F$ is a sheaf of sets.

---

Now I'm trying to understand if there is a way to do something like this between sheaves of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces (where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$) and (*not necessarily locally trivial*) Bundles of vector spaces.

That is, consider $\mathbb{F}$-$\mathrm{Bun}_B$ the category of spaces over $B$ endowed with a vector space structure on its fibers (such that the operations are continuous in the usual manner) and consider $\mathrm{Sh}_\mathbb{F}(B)$ the category of sheaves of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces over $B$.

There is a functor $\Gamma: \mathbb{F}$-$\mathrm{Bun}_B \to \mathrm{Sh}_\mathbb{F}(B)$ because of the continuity of the operations just like in the case of sets.

Now to construct a quasi-inverse $\operatorname{Et}: \mathrm{Sh}_\mathbb{F}(B) \to \mathbb{F}$-$\mathrm{Bun}_B$ I guess I would want to define a topology on the space  $\coprod_{b \in B}F_b$ making the canonical projection $\operatorname{Et}(F) = \coprod_{b \in B}F_b \to B$ into a (NNLT) $\mathbb{F}$-bundle.

The usual way is to define a topology making each section defined by $F(U)$ continuous, but this won't work: if $E \to B$ is the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R} \to \{*\}$, then $\operatorname{Et}(\Gamma(F))$ is $\mathbb{R} \to \{*\}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the discrete topology (ewwww).

**My question is:** Is there any way to do this construction and remember the $\mathbb{F}$'s topology so this construction defines an equivalence? Is an equivalence between these two categories even reasonable to expect in the first place?

---

A little motivation: All of this questions have arisen because I was trying to make some proofs of vector bundles simpler. For example if there is such an equivalence then maybe we can define the tensor produt and the direct sum of bundles in the world of sheaves! Of course, it's not haaaaaard to do these things in the topological world, but who knows?

Comment: I am not sure about the real case, but I know that for complex bundles, they are equivalent to locally free coherent sheaves, but these should be as modules over holomorphic functions on your space.

Comment: That being said, you can always regard a vector bundle as a sheaf of modules over functions on your space, and then the relevant constructions work

Comment: 1) Is this true even if you don't assume local triviality conditions? This would be a happy answer for the complex case.

Comment: You mean ignore local triviality for a vector bundle? Seems to me like you just drop the "locally free" bit

Comment: 2) When you say function do you mean possibly discontinuous ones? Is there a reference for this

Comment: I'm actually ignoring this in the question (but perhaps I didn't phrase it well - i didn't know which name to use instead!). Hopefully only the locally free condition drops, but, i'm not too optimistic about this

Comment: sure, you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem) and basically any book on complex geometry. For everything else, just google "vector bundles locally free sheaves"

Comment: and I meant continuous at least everywhere. I'm not sure how you drop this when we are working on topological spaces, just seems wrong to me

Comment: namely because everything is simpler if I know how the bundle works locally: I can just define the topology inherited from the product! For example if I have a constant sheaf associated to $V$ then I can define the quasi-inverse map to be $B \times V$ with the usual topology. Then we can glue (hopefully) using the canonical isomorphisms on the intersections.

Comment: Oh you absolutely do not need sheaves to do this. You will get some pushout (gluing) of cartesian products. Please see page 14 [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf). This is quite similar to the "etale space" you mention in your post.

Comment: Interesting you mentioned this, because it was exactly this proof that made me wonder if a sheaf theoretical proof was possible. Maybe I'm going in circles and doing things the complicated way...